# Is contradictory that in a mapping two disjoints sets have the same preimage?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f:A \longrightarrow B $ and $B=X \cup Y$, with $X\cap Y=\emptyset $. Also, $f^{-1}(X)=f^{-1}(Y)=A$. Is this contradictory? I think if that is the case, then there would exist $y_1\in X$, $ y_2\in Y$ such that $f(x)=y_1,y_2$ for some $x\in A$, but this would be impossible because $f$ is a mapping.

Comment: You are assuming that the sets in question are non-empty. But the data you have don't give you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe is not contradictory: you can take $A$, $B$, $f$, $X$ and $Y$ all empty. If any of these sets is non-empty, then you get a contradiction. Your argument is assuming that one of the sets is non-empty, but there is nothing in the statement of the problem to justify that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As Arthan pointed out, the statement is true in the case where all the sets are empty. Otherwise:

Your proof is correct. Well done!

You can also use the fact that $f^{-1}(X)\cap f^{-1}(Y)=f^{-1}(X\cap Y)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos My bad. Thank you for pointing this out!